# How to save trained Neural Network (Number recognitio from image)

Tags: java, neural-network

I have written a neural network program to train for recognition digits from image using back propagation and feed-forward. Its working quite good. I just wanted to know that how do i save this trained neural network since i don't know what to save. My objective is to train my neural network just once because it takes very long time to train (1000 iteration, and many training sets) and then i want to save it and load it for later use. I hope u understand my problem. I cannot reveal all my neural codes. But this is how execution code looks like

```
NeuralNetwork nn = new NeuralNetwork(numberOfInputs, nuberOfHiddenNodes, numberOfOuputNodes);
pattern less than patternsList.length:
nn.train(pattern);
```

Comment: Save the weights of each input to each neuron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class NeuralNetwork implements Serializable { ... }
```

Chain `ObjectOutputStream` with `FileOutputStream`.  Call the method `writeObject(...)` to write the `NeuralNetwork` object.

Comment: yeah  How could i not thought of it ? :D Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

After your network is trained you can store (and later load) the in-memory contents of `NeuralNetwork` and its children using [Java Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).